# flask get the varible

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to flask and jinja,recently I'm writing a project,
I have a list of 'user' objects reading from database,

```
@app.route('/userManage.html',methods=['GET','POST'])
def userManage():
    user_lst = db.users()
    return render_template('manager_temps/userManage.html', user_lst=user_lst)
```

the html is:

```
 {% for user in user_lst %}
 <tr class="row">
 <td class="col-md-1">
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value={$data.login_id} id={$data.login_id}>
 </td>
 <td class="col-md-2">{{user.c_id}}</td>
 <td class="col-md-2">{{user.c_name}}</td>
 <td class="col-md-2">{{user.enroll_time}}</td>
 {% if user.is_checked %}
 <td class="col-md-2"> yes</td>
 <td class="col-md-2">
 </td>
 {% else %}
 <td class="col-md-2"> no</td>
 <td class="col-md-2">

 <input type="submit"  name="check" value = 'admit' class="btn btn-info btn-xs btndistance" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCheck" onclick="" style = "margin-left:-30px;"></input>
 <input type="submit"  name="check" value = 'refuse' class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btndistance" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAlter" onclick=""></input>                            
 </td>
 {% endif %}
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

In browser part of it seems like this:[the image of the html above in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRYYk.png)

now when I click the button which value is 'admit' or 'refuse',I can get the form and know its value using request.form['check'],but how can I know which user in the list is chosen? I want to get the user object being clicked so that I can use it in my function userManage() in my .py file.

It has confusing me a long time,thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: why don't you just put the `user.c_id` in the `value` within the `input` tag? So the `input` tag will be like the following, `<input type="submit"  name="check" value ={{ 'admit_' ~ user.c_id }} class="btn btn-info btn-xs btndistance" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCheck" onclick="" style = "margin-left:-30px;"></input>`

Comment: I used to do this and I can get the value from the form,but I think it doen't look good in the browser,In the picture I posted in my question you can see the user_id is the first comlumn,I think it's redundancy if I write it in the button.